# Homepage cannot be found

Tags: url-rewriting, site-url

I have been developing a clients website on a subdirectory, and I just moved it into the main directory. I updates the site url and used Velvet Blues Update URLs plugin to update the rest of the url issues. All of my pages and images are showing up fine, but for some reason the home page can't be found. Any thoughts?

[Here](http://wwww.capstoneroofingco.com) is the link to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Visiting your domain name redirects to domain.com/**index.html** and that's where your issue is - WordPress doesn't know what index.html is and throws 404 error. The redirection might be caused by many things, hard to tell just by visiting your homepage. Are you sure that you've setup the WordPress URL and Home URL settings correctly? How about your .htaccess file? Maybe that's coming from your server's setup?

Comment: the URLs are definitely correct. What would I be looking for in the .htaccess file?

Comment: .htaccess looks pretty standard.

Comment: @AHinson Do you even have index.html file in your root? If yes - just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html?$ / [NC,R,L]
```

into my .htacess above the WordPress section and that seem to correct it. There were some strange things going on because the client previously did his website with Weebly so I had to do a little cleaning up.